# Unexpected EOF in a bash script, why?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I can't normally run sh scripts. It's confusing. I set the permissions to 777 and +x so it should work with the 'sh' command, right...

But it's working very strange. For example this scripts works ok:

```
echo "hello"
```

it prints "hello" with no errors. But this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 1 5`; do 
    echo $i
done
```

...outputs this error:

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "done")
```

Is there something wrong with that loop?

Comment: How do you run the above script? The loop it looks ok.

Comment: I run it with the sh command: sh script.sh

Comment: You defined `bash` and not `sh` for your script, so run it with `bash script.sh`

Comment: Are you sure that you have the last line (`done`) in your original script (`script.sh`)?

Comment: @Frantique This problem does nothing have to do with your observation.

Comment: The last line "done" i have... 100% sure :)

Comment: with "bash script.sh" I get the same error...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem it is, that you probably made a `Ctrl+C` `Ctrl+V` from a website, and the end-of-line char there was something strange, not printable character. (You can make it visible by dumping to hex the file.)

Please open your file in an editor, and retype everything manually, or at least remove the last eol characters, save your work, and try again.